# How to fix TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, typeerror

My UI crashes and I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

at v (helper.js:16)
at i (lodash.min.js:9)
at t (lodash.min.js:59)
at value (CheckAll.js:15)
```

Here's a snippet of the helper.js code:

```
export const updatedChecked = (items, checked) => items.map(item => ({ ...item, checked }));

export const filterChecked = (items, checked) => items.filter(item => item.checked === checked);

export const moveAtTheTop = (items, itemIds) => pureReverse(itemIds).reduce((acc, v) => {
 const toCutIndex = acc.findIndex(item => item.id === v);
 const toCut = acc.splice(toCutIndex, 1)[0];
 toCut.checked = true;
 acc.unshift(toCut);
 return acc;
}, updateChecked(items, false));

export const normalizeSrcItems = items => filterChecked(items, true).map(item => item.id);
```

Comment: Where do you ever call `normalizeSrcItems` and what do you pass to it?

Comment: you need to figure out why `items` is undefined.  You could patch this up many different ways, like default `items` arg in `normalizeSrcItems` as `[]` or `items?.filter(...)`etc, but it really depends on whether in your app it is valid for `items` to be undefined or not, and if it's valid, them you need a nullish check for items (`if (items)` etc) or if its not a valid scenario, then you have a bug in your code that has `items` being `undefined` when it shouldn't be

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you send `undefined` in `items` argument when you call `normalizeSrcItems`. You need to check it where you call it

```js
if (items) {
  normalizeSrcItems(items)
}
```

, or check why you have empty items, perhaps you get it in wrong way

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, calling

```
items.filter(...)
```

Looks like items is undefined. Quick fix is:

```
(items || []).filter(...)
```

But it might not solve the problem, why items are undefined.